# How to create a for inside other for in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, vector

I have 2 vectors of different sizes:

- vector1 = [1, 2, 3]
- vector2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

I want to make operations between them. Each number from the vector1 plus each number from the vector2. Something like that:

[image]

I'm trying unsuccessfully a `for` inside a `for`. Any help?

```
vector1 <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 3))
vector2 <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

for (i in vector1) {
  for (j in vector2) {
  a <- i + j
}
}
```

This is the message error

```
Warning message:
In i + j : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `outer`

```
> vector1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
> vector2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
> outer(vector1, vector2, FUN="+")
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    3    4    5    6
[2,]    3    4    5    6    7
[3,]    4    5    6    7    8
```

If you really want to use a loop, you can use a nested `for` loop:

```
> result <- matrix(0, nrow = length(vector1), ncol=length(vector2))
> for(i in seq_len(length(vector1))){
    for(j in seq_len(length(vector2))){
      result[i,j] <- sum(vector1[i], vector2[j])
    }
 }
> result
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    3    4    5    6
[2,]    3    4    5    6    7
[3,]    4    5    6    7    8
```

Answer (score 1):

`for` is a very inefficient way to do this. Here's a way using `sapply` from base R although I feel there should be an even better way -

```
c(sapply(vector1, function(x) x + vector2))

# [1] 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8
```